# e-Learning platform that supports video streaming for classes

Tags: open-source, video, educational, video-conferencing, intranet

I'm looking for an e-Learning platform that supports video streaming, sort of like [moodle](https://moodle.org/) but with support for live classes by company instructors.

This is intended to be only used inside the business, so access to courses and materials created by others are not needed ([Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/), [Teachable](https://teachable.com/)), all content will be created and cosumed by company employees, so having the option to sell created content it's not wanted either ([Educadium](http://www.educadium.com/)).

There are other options like [ezTalks webinar](https://www.eztalks.com/webinar), which allow real-time classes, but do not support video streaming which is a must.

The application should ideally be hosted locally, as moodle allows you to.

Open source suggestions are prefered.

Answer (score 1):

edX (https://edX.org), which started by providing courses from leading universities online, has now made the platform free and open source (https://open.edx.org/about-open-edx) for any organization to host its own courses/ training modules for internal/commercial use.

You will get the required video streaming support and since you won't need to sell the content it should not be an issue that the e-commerce module is not a part of the default installation of the application.

You can host the application locally or on the cloud with your choice of service provider.

[About video](https://youtu.be/UdawuO-o7AQ)

[Getting started](https://opensource.com/article/18/6/getting-started-open-edx)

[MOOC: How to create the course](https://www.edx.org/course/edx101-overview-of-creating-an-edx-course)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect Moodle with [BigBlueButton](https://bigbluebutton.org/). This gives you the open source solution you need.

Our open source platform, [edloomio](https://edloomio.com), can also be setup with BigBlueButton. Send me a PM if you are interested.